# W3 Total Cache links to http instead of https

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, ssl

We seem to have a problem with W3 Total Cache plugin (I think). On normal pages, it works good and minified CSS and JS has the https:// prefix in the HTML head, but when we navigate to a subpage (for example /news/subpage/) the prefix for minified CSS and JS is http://. It obviously gets blocked then, and CSS doesn't work.

I'm new to Wordpress and should fix this, but I have no idea how. I already searched into the code of the plugin, but couldn't really find anything clear to change. Also I've looked into template head file, but couldn't find the links, so they're probably being generated by W3 Total Cache plugin.

Can anybody help me out a little?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check this plugin. 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/
May be this plugin is useful for you to change the url in database to replace your existing old url to new one where you can add old http link to new https link.I hope this one can solve your issue

Comment: Is not able to fix without another plugin? Or maybe through code? Thank you for your answer though.

Comment: Find in your database there may be the http:// urls which causing the issue.

Comment: Are you solved your problem using that plugin? On google, you can find more plugin to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was just a setting within W3 Total Cache. I had to check the setting 'Cache SSL (https) requests' under Page Cache.

Comment: oh gosh, thanks for this! have had this problem for ages but was unable to resolve it until now! :)

Comment: I'm happy I could help you!